# iTunes 10 file directory organization in Windows

Tags: itunes, windows, macos

I'm pretty new to iTunes.

I have a video series that I want it to be imported to iTunes and be organized in this hierarchy:

Artist->DVD No. and Title->Lesson No. and Title

The files are now organized using Windows 7 Tags \ File system.

Example:

```
D:\My Videos\John Due\Learning about Birds\4 - The Wings\2 - Advantages
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use iTunes to manage your media files, it's best to stop bothering about file system structure for these media files and just let iTunes do its magic. Any specific sorting and selecting can then be done directly in iTunes (at least after you updated all the metadata).

In your case I would probably import all the files and then use playlists and playlist folders inside iTunes to get the structure I want:

[image]

Comment: 1) But will the playlist and their folders remain the same way in iPod after sync? 2) What if I can't stand it when peeping into the iTunes\Movies folder and see the iTunes causes magic of chaos and it does bother me, is there any way to set this up?

Comment: I tried creating a playlist-folder tree, but it doesn't allow me adding videos to the folder, I guess I'll have to create individual playlist in each folder. This is too sucky.

Comment: I tried setting the album for each DVD set, but that didn't help much.

Comment: Turn of "Copy files to iTunes Media folder" and "Keep iTunes folder organized" in Advanced Preferences if you want to keep the files on disk in the current structure. As for the folder/playlist thing, I've extended the answer accordingly, hopefully it's a bit clearer now.

Comment: @Shimmy Letting iTunes do its magic is worth it in the long run... I stopped caring how the files are organized on disk long ago. If all you want is "nested playlists", you can do this using a Smart Playlist that contains items from the other playlists (or by artist/album).